# How to remove first line from a String

Tags: bash, shell

Hello I want to remove a line from a string but I just found inside a file like `sed -i 1d file`
 but I didn't find for string variable in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try v.gr.

```
string=$(echo "$string" | sed 1d)
```

Comment: Your code of course works for bash **and** POSIX shell, but has the drawback that the resulting string undergoes all the treatment of `echo`. At least it would be advisable to use `echo -n`. Maybe it would be worth to also point out a more efficient bash-only solution, which does not use `echo`: `string=$(sed 1d <<<$string)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this directly in bash:

```
string=${string#*$'\n'}
```

This is an example of the parameter expansion `${var#prefix}`, which removes `prefix` from the variable `var`. In this case, it removes everything up to and including the first newline character, represented in bash by `$'\n'`.

In shells other than bash you can use a literal newline instead:

```
string=${string#*
}
```